# What if we would fill room with face drawings? Would that change us?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, personality

I mean like if there would be a room in which we are spending most of the day working, sleeping etc. This room would be filled with eyes/faces drawing and painting on walls. Treat it like room from horror movies, something like this:
[image: wall painting example]

Would spending a lot of time in that kind of room change our personality/mood? In some way influence us? I don't mean it like getting used to watching horrors, but changing without 'us noticing'.

And in other way around can room filled with happy images like smiles, i dont know stuff like this , can make us more 'happy'?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried googling/researching answer on your own? What was result of your effort? You should show some work

Comment: What are you basing yourself on? (Why is this question any more interesting than ""What if we would fill rooms with drawings of flowers?") What is your reason for asking this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific to your questions, I am not aware of any research on connection between "face" pattern and mood.

But of course, changing surroundings will have an affect. There are number of papers on how color affects mood and productivity of workers. For example, in ["Impact of Three Interior Color Schemes on Worker Mood and Performance Relative to Individual Environmental Sensitivity"](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Nancy_Kwallek/publication/232444027_Effects_of_office_interior_color_on_workers'_mood_and_productivity/links/0deec52e9833b10a61000000.pdf)

> The findings on mood definitely suggest that color scheme alone may impact mood states in accordance with previous findings.

However, it is worth noticing that human brain (as well as simpler animals) has great capacity for [habituation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habituation): ability to "get used" to non-threatening stimuli.

Comment: Yeah, color influence on mood is better known stuff. That's why hospitals use white etc.

Comment: There's a fairly recent review of color-related psychology https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23808916

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too broad of a question, but looking at "cute" stuff improves concentration, apparently (and I'm saying that because it's only based on [one](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0046362) or [two](https://doi.org/10.1037/a0014904) studies), where

> Cute objects are assumed to be characterized by baby schema. This is a set of features that are commonly seen in young animals: a large head relative to the body size, a high and protruding forehead, large eyes, and so forth.

Comment: wow that is so cool :) Now 9000-item brony collection on my desk is justified!